# I think I shorted my pi's gpio pins

Tags: gpio, pi-4

I think I fried my raspberry pi 4B ( revision 1.5 I think ). I was powering it via the gpio pins ( pin 2 and 6 ). Unfortunately since I was using crocodile clips I think I have touched GND with pin 8.
Now my pi just shows solid red light with no other signs of life. Removing any peripherals doesn't seem to do anything. My only hope is probably if there is some sort of fuse which I can replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poking at header pins with anything except a Dupont connector is a recipe for disaster - croc clips are possibly the worst choice.

You probably shorted pins 1,2 which is almost invariably fatal as it kills the PMIC. (I put a dummy Dupont connector on pin 1 if I am not using it to prevent any accidental contact.)

Get a new Pi and some Dupont cables. I would also recommend you get an official power supply.

---

If you want to check, measure the voltage on pin 1 - if it isn't 3.3V it is dead.

**DO NOT** poke at pins with a multimeter - use Dupont cables or a proper micro connector.

Comment: Is it fixable? What can I do at the moment?

Comment: We can't tell if it's fixable.  Look on-line for some tests you could do if you have the needed test kit.

Comment: I measured on pins 2 and 6, it shows 5V, but on pins 1 and 6 it shows 0V

Comment: @DanielZaprev: Looks like your Pi is dead, but you should upvote/accept the answer...  it is an accurate answer.